# How to change size of controls in a view in iPad?

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to change size of line width of arc layer for iPad as follows but it is not working.

```
  func setup() {

        let model = UIDevice.current.model
        if model == "iPad" {

            backgroundArcLayer.lineWidth =  36.0
            backgroundArcLayer.fillColor = nil
            backgroundArcLayer.strokeEnd = 2
            layer.addSublayer(backgroundArcLayer)
            frontArcLayer.lineWidth = 36.0
            frontArcLayer.fillColor = nil
            frontArcLayer.strokeEnd = 1.0
            layer.addSublayer(frontArcLayer)

        }

        backgroundArcLayer.lineWidth =  18.0
        backgroundArcLayer.fillColor = nil
        backgroundArcLayer.strokeEnd = 1
        layer.addSublayer(backgroundArcLayer)
        frontArcLayer.lineWidth = 18.0
        frontArcLayer.fillColor = nil
        frontArcLayer.strokeEnd = 0.5
        layer.addSublayer(frontArcLayer)  
    }
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Never do anything based on the model. Make all adjustments based on the view's size.

Comment: These controls are inside view, which were created using programmatically, so how do I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you're overwriting all the properties you've set in your `if` statement by not having the rest of your method in an `else` body.

Comment: Such a basic mistake :(

Comment: I also want to add, check "model=iPad" is not good really. Apple could change that property in the future and your code breaks.

Comment: @GeneCode , so what do I do.Can you please provide an example, because those controls inside are created programmatically

Comment: This is better: [UIDevice currentDevice].userInterfaceIdiom == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad

Comment: @GeneCode, that helps to make it better

Answer (score 1):

You declare iPhone and iPad globally for accessing any where in your project. Then try like this:

```
 let IsIPhone = UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == UIUserInterfaceIdiom.phone
 let IsIPad = UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == UIUserInterfaceIdiom.pad
```

You can check the iPhone and iPad with this:

```
 func setup() {

   if IsIPad{

        backgroundArcLayer.lineWidth =  36.0
        backgroundArcLayer.fillColor = nil
        backgroundArcLayer.strokeEnd = 2
        layer.addSublayer(backgroundArcLayer)
        frontArcLayer.lineWidth = 36.0
        frontArcLayer.fillColor = nil
        frontArcLayer.strokeEnd = 1.0
        layer.addSublayer(frontArcLayer)

    }else{

        backgroundArcLayer.lineWidth =  18.0
        backgroundArcLayer.fillColor = nil
        backgroundArcLayer.strokeEnd = 1
        layer.addSublayer(backgroundArcLayer)
        frontArcLayer.lineWidth = 18.0
        frontArcLayer.fillColor = nil
        frontArcLayer.strokeEnd = 0.5
        layer.addSublayer(frontArcLayer)  
    }
}
```

Its good for checking iPad and iPhone.